Calculate image bluriness metric in flutter
How do I get a metric for bluriness/sharpness of an image in flutter? I'm making an OCR app and would like to automatically take a picture once the text is in focus, and not blurry. I don't need anything cinematographic. I just need to compare some video frames, and when the image has become significantly sharper, trigger something.
Since I want to perform this operation in real-time, I need something decently fast. There are a lot of very fancy edge detection algorithms out there, but I don't need the fanciness. The simplest way I found was from wikipedia. Below is a screenshot of the wikipedia page as an illustration.  After applying the kernel to the image, I could tell by the amount of black and white pixels versus grey pixels how sharp the image was. It seems like a pretty fast approach, but I don't know enough about statistics and writing fast code to be certain.
How would I implement something like this in flutter? I know that I'd be able to implement something like this in python with openCV, numpy and PIL. I don't know which package / approach to use in flutter.

The quickest and dirtiest focussing metric is to maximise the sum of absolute differences between adjacent pixels (vertical and horizontal). BTW Your sample image doesn't look much like text to me...

This question is similar to: Blur Detection of image using OpenCV. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have edited the question for clarity. Obviously, this question is not similar at all to the question that @ChristophRackwitz linked, since it's a python question and mine is flutter. I hope that the current state is obvious enough for the moderators liking. If it's not then I don't know what is.

Please show your code

"obviously", the programming of it is the trivial part, compared to knowing what to do in the first place. flutter interoperates with javascript or webassembly, right? then you can use anything that gives you pixel access. -- that's asking for recommendations, which is off-topic for [so]. [help/on-topic] -- none of us are moderators. we are people who answer questions in this site. for free. I understand if you'd like better service but that's the best we can offer for free.
